# Remove image extension, rename and restore

Tags: php, string, filenames

Say the image is called:`gecko.jpg`

Can I first remove ".jpg" and add "-100x100" after "gecko", and then put the extension back, so it would be "gecko-100x100.jpg"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, quite simply with PHP's string functions in conjunction with [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.basename.php)

```
$base = basename($filename, ".jpg");
echo $base . "-100x100" . ".jpg";
```

Or to do it with any filetype using [`strrpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strrpos.php) to locate the extension by finding the last `.`

```
// Use strrpos() & substr() to get the file extension
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, "."));
// Then stitch it together with the new string and file's basename
$newfilename = basename($filename, $ext) . "-100x100" . $ext;
```

--

```
// Some examples in action...
$filename = "somefile.jpg";
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, "."));
$newfilename = basename($filename, $ext) . "-100x100" . $ext;
echo $newfilename;
// outputs somefile-100x100.jpg

// Same thing with a .gif
$filename = "somefile.gif";
// outputs somefile-100x100.gif
```

Answer (score 5):

use [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/pathinfo)

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');
$new = $path_parts['filename'] . '-100x100.' .$path_parts['extension'];
```